# WSO2 APIM Analytics Not Showing Any statistics

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have setup WSO2 API manager and also APIM Analytics but we are not able to see any analytical data in publisher or store.

We see the message "Data Publishing Enabled. Generate some traffic to see statistics". 
 We also checked in the database and don't see any records added to the database tables.

Comment: Have you generated data? There is a scheduler which will summarize the event for each 5 mins.

Comment: I Hit the url (production) from API details, many times and then i checked analytics but there i got the message. "Data Publishing Enabled. Generate some traffic to see statistics".

Comment: Which version of API Manager and Analytics you are using?

Comment: wso2am-2.1.0 ,

wso2am-analytics-2.1.0

Comment: @VinayTomar
I have this problem also
Did you already solve this problem?